# Grouping joined data in Hadoop map-reduce

Tags: java, join, hadoop, mapreduce

I have two different types of files, the one type is a list of users. It have following structure:
**UserID,Name,CountryID**

And the second type is orders list:
**OrderID,UserID,OrderSum**

Each user have lots of orders. I need to write map-reduce hadoop job (in java) and receive output with following structure:
**CountryID,NumOfUsers,MinOrder,MaxOrder**

It's not a problem for me to write a two different mappers (for each file type) and one reducer in order to join data from both files by UserID, and receive following structure:
**UserID,CountryID,UsersMinOrder,UsersMaxOrder**

But i don't understand how do i group that data by **CountryID**?

Comment: Shameless plug for my book "MapReduce Design Patterns". It has an entire chapter on joins that tells you how to implement them. (sorry for not giving you an answer, it's long and I don't have time right now)

Comment: why do you need it to be in Java? why not use something like Pig for this? (and by the way Donald's book is indeed a good reference for common map/reduce problems and how to tackle them)

Comment: @DonaldMiner thanks will read your book.

Comment: @ArnonRotem-Gal-Oz this is a task on my studies, i should solve it without using Pig or any other tools.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd recommend this running this through Pig or Hive, as you can then solve this kind of thing with just a few lines.

Failing that, I would do the following.  Run another MapReduce job on your joined data, and do the following:  in your mapper, for each input split keep tabs on min order, max order, and number of tuples (rows with unique user id) processed per country id.  There are only a few countries, so you can keep these stats in memory throughout the map job.  At the end of the split, output accumulated stats to the reducer keyed by country id.  Then the reducer simply combines aggregated data from each split to find the global max, min and count.

Comment: This is a task on my studies, i should solve it without using Pig or any other tools. And it should by a single map-reduce job, thus i can't run another job on my joined data.

Comment: Actually you was right, i just chained two map-reduce jobs and solved that problem.